# Why is array[4,43] == [] for an array of size 4 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a[4,43]
# => []
a[5,43]
# => nil
```

What is the reason for this anomaly?

Comment: We do not understand your question, please edit.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois I think most answerers did not understand the question because you edited it into something different.

Comment: There were answers already before my edit. However my edit was not useful and I'm glad somebody else changed it :) Either way I think the question would need a clarification.

Comment: Edited @Pierre-LouisGottfrois. I hope it's clearer now...

Comment: @sepp2k check out the edited explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with spartacus and the bug reporter from the link by Dylan -- there are indeed inconsistencies and Array#slice could use a change.  Although yes, it is the spec; from [Array#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice)

> > For `start` and `range` cases the starting index is just before an element. Additionally, an empty array is returned when the starting index for an element range is at the end of the array ... Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range.

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
^  ^  ^  ^  ^
0  1  2  3  4
```

Let's say the array a was constructed as [0,1,2,3] , and the numbers below the hats represent where one would "start" when using the a[start,length] form.  So a[0,0] is [], and a[1,0] is [], since we have not "hopped" anywhere.  Similarly, a[4,0] is [], and that's fine. 
Now a[4,x] where x is any nonzero number, **should return nil**, in my opinion, since a[4] is undefined, and in theory, a[4,x] is asking for an array that would look like [undefined, undefined...]

For ranges, however, it appears that an array is built from all indices that appear in the range, so the "hat" start visualization does not apply.  So a[0..2] returns [a[0],a[1](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice),a[2]], or [0,1,2] in this case. 
 a[4..x] **should return nil** for any x, since there is no a[4].

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a[5,43]
# => []
a[6,43]
# => nil
```

From http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4245:

> This is per spec.
>
> Think of it this way:
>
> [5..-1]: give me all elements after the 5th one and up to the last
> one. There are none, so []
>
> [6..-1]: give me all elements after the 6th
> one and up to the last one. Say what? There is no 6th one, so returns
> nil as the given request is out of bounds.

Comment: I went to the link but there is still an inconsistency because there is is no 5th element(index 4; i.e. [4, 43]) either.

Comment: @spartacus: Exactly. You deserve upvotes for discovering a bug in Ruby. Pleas go to http://bugs.ruby-lang.org and report an issue.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's by design. My sample code didn't match up to the quote below it. In your case, there is a 4th element, so you can say "After the 4th" (which is the end), but you can't say "After the 5th".

Comment: @DylanMarkow I don't think [5..-1] means "give me all elements after the 5th one and up to the last one". It means "[5..-1]: give me all elements after the index 5(6th) and up to the last one"

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel `[5..-1]` does include index 5... saying "after index 5" would mean "starting with index 6".

Comment: @DylanMarkow sorry I meant `[5,X]` where `X` is greater than one. It means `X` items starting from index `5` which doesn't exist. Please try `[0,2]`, `[1,2]`, `[2,2]`, `[3,2]`, `[4,2]`, `[5,2]` and `[6,2]` to see the anomaly.